# Does a Hermitian matrix remain Hermitian when transformed by an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: matrices

$A$ is a Hermitian matrix,

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
4& 3+4i\\
3-4i &31
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\bar A =\left(\begin{matrix}
4& 3-4i\\
3+4i &31
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Here, $A^{T}=\bar A$

A square matrix B, is said to be orthogonal if $B^{T}*B=B*B^{T}=I$

Comment: What do you mean by *transformed by an orthogonal matrix*?

Comment: You mean whether the orthogonal matrix to a Hermetian matrix is a Hermetian too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when $B$ are a real matrix with $B=\bar B$ you get 
$$
\left(\color{blue} B^T\cdot A \cdot \color{red}B\right)^T=\color{red}B^T\cdot A^T \cdot \color{blue}B=B^T\cdot\bar A \cdot B
=\bar B^T\cdot\bar A \cdot \bar B =\overline{\left(B^T\cdot A \cdot B\right)}.
$$